# Postgress database used as external hive metastore for databricks: "Fatal: sorry, too many clients already"

Tags: postgresql, hive, databricks, hive-metastore

I have moved my internal hive metastore to an external one and configured two of my clusters to point to it using this [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/data/metastores/external-hive-metastore.html) to set it up

Now for some reason I'm starting to see errors in the driver logs saying:

> ERROR BoneCP: Failed to acquire connection to connectionstring Sleeping for 7000 ms. Attempts left: 5
> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections

If I check pg_stat_activity I can see that the metastore gets spammed with idle connections that don't get closed again for some reason.

Have anyone experienced similar issues, and have a potential fix or workaround?

Much appreciated

[image]

Comment: how many clusters & nodes are connecting to this metastore?

Comment: In this case it's two clusters with a single node setup - but the idea is to use the metastore with 10+ clusters connecting to it.
I have switched away from using Azure Database for PostgreSQL server and over to the flexible server because it introduces PgBouncer for connection pooling. It seems to improve the situation a bunch. but I'm still in the testing phase